# c#でストアアプリで使用するSQLiteのDBを作りたい

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, database

初めまして。
前回の質問でたくさんのコメントを頂き、SQLiteを使用するための設定をするところまで行いました。
しかし、本当にSQLiteを触れるのかを確かめようとDB作成の仕方を調べてみたものの、System.Data.SQlite.dllを追加するやりかたしか見つかりませんでした。

SQLite for Windows Runtimeをインストールし、
SQLite for Windows Runtimeとc++2013を追加して、
sqlite-netをインストールすることろまでは終わっています。

xamlでボタンを作りました。MainPage.xaml.csにクリックイベントの処理を書き込むprivate void から始まる記述もあります。

```
private void conect_bt(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

この中にSQLiteでDBに接続する、もしくはDBを作成する記述を書くのでしょうか、
情報が見つからずDB接続が上手くいくかの確認ができずにいて困っています。

c#でSQliteを使い、ストアアプリで使用するDBを作成する記述とはどのようなものなのでしょうか？

参考になるサイトでも構いませんので教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: splite-netをインストールしたのなら[サンプル](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net#example-time)も見つかるはずですが…？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
sqlite-netはパッケージ管理からインストールしました。
英語頑張って読みます。

Comment: ググれば参考になるページが見つかると思いますが・・・。`ここまでやりました。続きを教えてください。`みたいなスタンスはどうなのかなぁ・・・と思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
ググッてもSystem.Data.SQLite.dllを使用したコードばかりですし、sayuriさんの提示してくださったようなサイトのコードを参考にしても上手く動かないので質問させて頂いています。
usingステートメントで使用される型は、暗黙的に'System.IDisposable'への変換が可能でなければいけませんといったものや、オーバーロードはありませんといったもの、などなど、様々なエラーが出てきます。エラーが出るのは当然としても、単語ひとつひとつ調べて行っても対処法の参考になるサイトというものはどうしても見つかりません。実際前回の質問でも、ストアアプリを作成するという前提で質問していたにも関わらずSystem.Data.SQLite.dllは使えないという根本的問題が提示されるまでにかなりの時間を要しました。これはネットでの情報量の少なさ故だと考えています。もちろん自分でも探してはいますが、なかなか見つからないから諦めるというのは違うと思います。そしてコードを書けではなく参考サイトはありますかという内容の質問です。ググッて見つかって上手く動いたら質問はしていません。知識技術を身に付けるために皆様の力をお借りしたいという事です。

Comment: Windows ストアアプリや C# については何も知らないのですが、「c#でストアアプリで使用するSQLiteのDB」で検索したら上位に [WindowsストアアプリでSQLiteを用いたローカルデータベースの利用 ～実装編～](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/imanyu/20121018/1350492128) などというページが出てきたのですけれども、ご希望には沿いませんか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
sayuriさんの提示してくださったサイトも、argusさんの提示してくださったサイトも私の希望通りのサイトだと思います。
c# ストアアプリ SQLiteのキーワードで検索するのが一番情報が出てくるのでしょうか。
提示していただいたサイトは環境構築の際に上手くいかなかったのでスルーしていました...
サイトには記載されていない（省略されてしまっている）、コードに必要不可欠な部分が何かを考えるのに手間取っています。
Loadedイベント内を実装するコードで、voidから始まっている理由がどうしても分からないのです。
public static voidで始まるクラスの定義かと思ったのですが違うのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問には「ストアアプリで使用するDBを作成する記述」としか書かれていませんので、「Loadedイベント内を実装するコードで~」は別の質問にしか見えません。質問内容を変えるか、もしくは別の質問にした方が良いのではないでしょうか。なお、C# のメソッドでアクセス修飾子が省略された場合は `private` 扱いになります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
確かに質問を変えたほうが良いですね。
省略が可能なんですか。分かりました。

Comment: 作成されたアプリケーションはWindows 7で動作しませんが大丈夫なのでしょうか？ 本当にストアアプリが適切な選択か今なお疑問です。
情報量が少ないのも当然です。.NET FrameworkはWindows 98から使用可能なのに対し、ストアアプリはWindows 8限りのものであり、Windows 10からはユニバーサルアプリへと変更されています。そのため今後もストアアプリに関する情報が増えることはほとんどありません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
私の環境はWindows8.1なので大丈夫だと思いますが、何か別の環境の問題なのでしょうか？
ストアアプリが適切かと言われれば、私は製作依頼に従って動いているだけですのでなんとも言えません。
あまりにも情報が少ないのでおかしいとは思いましたが、Windows10のことを忘れていました。確かに情報が増える機会はあまりなさそうですね。

Answer (score 1):

実装することができましたので、ここにソースコードを置きたいとと思います。

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // データベース保存先と，データベースファイルの名前を決める
        var dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Food.db");
        // dbpathで指定したデータベースファイルに，接続する
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
        {
            // テーブルを作成
            db.CreateTable<Food>();
            // トランザクション処理
            db.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                // レコードの作成
                db.Insert(new Food() { Name = "醤油ラーメン", Price = 500, Calorie = 700 });
                db.Insert(new Food() { Name = "きつねうどん", Price = 350, Calorie = 500 });
                db.Insert(new Food() { Name = "カレーライス", Price = 450, Calorie = 1000 });
                db.Insert(new Food() { Name = "ポテトチップス", Price = 200, Calorie = 600 });
            });

            // ListViewのソースに設定する
            Food_listview.ItemsSource = db.Table<Food>();
        }
    }

}

public class Food
{
    // 主キー，自動連番
    [AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // カラムの型と名前
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Calorie { get; set; }

    // 出力形式
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("ID : {0}\t商品名：{1}\t価格：{2}円\tカロリー：{3}kcal",Id, Name, Price, Calorie);
    }
}
```

コメントを下さった皆様、ありがとうございました。